# Reference request: subspace-based generalisation of weak* convergence

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, ap.analysis-of-pdes, measure-theory

Let $V$ be a normed space and $(V_j)_{j\in [0,1]}$ be a family of linear subspaces of $V$ with $V_1$ non-trivial and such that $V_1\subsetneq V_j\subseteq V_i$ whenever $i\leq j$. We write $W:=V'$ for the topological dual of $V$.

Recall that a net $(\phi_\alpha)\subset W$ is weak* convergent to $\phi\in W$ if $\phi_\alpha(x)\rightarrow^\ast\phi(x)$ for each $x\in V$.

Given the subspaces of $V$, we can weaken this convergence by passing to the restricted pointwise convergence
$$\tag{1}\phi_\alpha\rightarrow^j\phi \quad :\Leftrightarrow \quad \lim_{\alpha}\phi_\alpha(x)=\phi(x) \ \text{ for each } x\in V_j,$$
for any given $j\in[0,1]$. This notion of convergence can be further weakened by defining

$$\tag{2}\phi_\alpha\rightarrow\phi \quad :\Leftrightarrow \quad \phi_\alpha\rightarrow^j\phi \ \ \text{ for some } \ 0\leq j < 1.$$

**Question:** Do you know if the (notion of) convergence $(2)$ defines a topology that goes by a special name? And have you seen this studied or applied anywhere?

Comment: Isn't (2) the same as asking that $\phi_{\alpha}(x)\to\phi(x)$ for all $x\in V_1$ ?

Comment: @ChristianRemling Yes, you are right, thanks for pointing that out. I corrected the definition.

Comment: Not sure if something can be said in this generality. One case could be: The $V_j$ are spaces of Hölder continuous functions and V are the continuous function. In this case, nothing interesting happens, if I see correctly.

Comment: @Dirk The case you mentioned is similar to the context where I came across this. Suppose that we specialised this case further by declaring $V$ as the space of bounded functions on some space $X$ (of Lipschitz functions) which are continuous wrt. the Lip-norm on $X$, so that $W$ becomes the space of (regular, finite etc.) rba measures on $\mathcal{B}(X)$ [the Borel sigm-algebra on $X$]; suppose further that the $V_j$ are the spaces of bounded functions on $X$ that are continuous wrt. the $(1-j)$-Hölder norm on $X$ $(j<1)$, with $V_1$ the space of bounded, uniformly continuous functions on $X$.

Comment: Would you then be inclined to say that the (2)-induced topology on $W$ is '(only) very slightly stronger' than the uniform weak*-topology on $W$ (that is, the topology induced by the convergence $\rightarrow^1$)? This could be a consequence that I would find interesting in my context.